# Examples of people that have really low name recogniton?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, phrasing, humor

Not exactly sure how to phrase the title, but here's the sentence I'm asking about:

*Our job? Somehow get XXXXX, (a candidate with less name recognition than _____ ) to the top of the polls.*

I was considering using some obscure historical figure (e.g. than the 5th president of Latvia), but not sure if that comes off kinda cringy. Thanks!

Comment: Less name recognition than a ham sandwich?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made clear that John Doe was a placeholder name--sorry for any confusion this may have caused. I have updated the post.

Comment: If they had really no name recognition, then nobody would know who they were and so the joke wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, you could always use "Jude the Obscure".

Comment: Do you like *Plonee Almonee* (PLOH-nee al-MOH-nee)? Right out of the Talmud, for 'Anonymous, the son of Nobody'.

Comment: Funny as "less name recognition than ABC" is, it would be kinder to say *a candidate without name recognition*. ABC may eventually read your quip.

Comment: You would do better to get someone with name recognition for having failed to win election. Their notoriety, not name recognition is what you are trying to tread on.

Comment: I'll never forget Whatsisname!!!